# Java environment location is 'not a valid identifier'

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I'm trying to set my JAVA_HOME variable in my hadoop-env.sh file manually, but the path to my Java bin file is 'not a valid identifier' according to Cygwin.

I get the following error message, I believe I have escaped all special characters correctly

```
S@W27 /cygdrive/c/hadoop-1.2.1
 $ bin/hadoop
 /cygdrive/c/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: 
 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7': not a valid identifier
```

I have tried the same file path with forward slashes, and also with /bin/java at the end but with no success.

Why is the path invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey Simon the path should be with **" "** in forward slash or in backward slash without qoute like this :-

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
export JAVA_HOME=/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7   #(as the root is C drive)
```

and in hadoop installation it is strictly mentioned that you have to set your JAVA path to

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Java\jre8"
```

that should not be inside the program files.

Comment: It is just started ,welcome to the world of HADOOP in WINDOWS.

Comment: The example with forward slashes is incorrect. Any value which contains spaces needs to be in quotes. In Bourne-family shells, including Bash, single quotes are used around verbatim strings, while double quotes are "weaker" (so, for example, backslashes in double-quoted strings should properly be doubled to represent a literal backslash).

Answer (score 0):

export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
or
export JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7 will work.

Make sure that don't give space between = and path
export JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7(invalid)

Comment: In the first part of your answer, you said [export JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7 will work] Sorry, that is incorrect. Because you have to include your path in double quotes because there is a space between Program & Files. In the second part of your answer, you said [Make sure that don't give space between = and path export JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7(invalid)] Sorry, that is incorrect also because you are missing the double quote from the path. The space between = and path does not make any difference. You have to include your path in the double quote to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME= ${/usr/local/jdk1.8} 


**warn:** must  {}
```

Comment: Hi Mingzhao. Thank you for your contribution. But please try to give proper answers with at least some explanation. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.