# Not a valid identifier every time I launch git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

Every time I open git bash this :

```
bash: export: `Files/PuTTY:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program': not a 
valid identifier
 bash: export: `Files/nodejs:/c/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program'
: not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `Code/bin:/c/Users/Me/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl': not a valid identifier
```

I'm not sure why and how to fix this. Any help?

Comment: Check the `export` statements in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java environment location is 'not a valid identifier'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904897/java-environment-location-is-not-a-valid-identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set (and, apparently, `export`) a variable to a value which contains whitespace, you need to quote it. Change

```
export PATH=/c/Program Files:other stuff:/more/things
```

to

```
export PATH="/c/Program Files:other stuff:/more/things"
```

where obviously I had to guess a great deal about what the erroneous assignment might look roughly like. It's apparently in one of your Bash startup files, so it should not be too hard to find.

(If the value only contains verbatim text, it's better to use single quotes; but I'm guessing it might contain e.g. `$PATH` which needs to be in double quotes to work correctly.)

In case it's not blindingly obvious, the erroneous example above attempts to set and export two variables, `PATH` and `stuff:/more/things` where the latter is not a valid variable identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above solution worked for you, this error can also be caused by incorrect encoding. For example, if you use special characters, you must mask them as URL-encoding to avoid errors. In my case

`export PATH="text§text"`

had to be replaced by

`export PATH="text%C2%A7text"`

to work. Visit https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/369 for further information.